# Why is date_format(?,'%d-%b-%y') failing in node?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using node to scrape some data and insert it into a table

The retrieved data is in the form ['03-Jan-14',20.18]

I have the SQL set up like this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO data (data_date, data_value) VALUES (date_format(?,\'%d-%b-%y\'),?)";
var insert_data = [parsedResults.data_date, parsedResults.data_value];
sql = mysql.format(sql, insert_data);
```

When I run the script I get this

```
INSERT INTO data (data_date, data_value) VALUES (date_format('03-Jan-14','NaN-%b-%y'), 20.18)
```

I've done some google searching and can't find a reason for this.

It seems as though JavaScript is interpreting %d rather than passing it as is.

Would love to get some insight on this problem.

Not looking for work-arounds, I want to know why this is failing in this particular way.

Comment: Once you work around that particular problem (looks like the `%d` being interpreted as a `printf`-style decimal)... the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function expects a valid `date` value as the first argument. If the `data_date` column is datatype `DATE`, I think you are wanting to use -[**`STR_TO_DATE`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), the inverse of `DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: FWIW the backslash in `\'` is unnecessary because your SQL string is enclosed in double quotes, so just `'` will do.

Comment: Also, I just tested your code with the `mysql` module (2.7.0) and I cannot reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: You're right about str_to_date of course. I knew date_format was wrong, and I got side tracked and forgot to check the proper function to use.
Now the remaining question is why is is interpreting %d?

Comment: What was your test code @mscdex?

Comment: @KenIngram I used the exact same code you have shown.

Comment: And what was the result of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install the dateFormat npm module and format the date using that tool. Using MySQL str_to_date was then unnecessary.

I think this is probably much easier than having the SQL handle it.

I still have no idea how to prevent %d from being translated as a sprintf parameter.

Comment: Many years after, does anyone have a solution for this? I have the exact same problem! %d is being translated to NaN!

Comment: Did you try using '%%d' ?

Comment: Yes, it partially worked but the formatting was sent in the wrong way. I pass "%Y-%m-%d" as a parameter of formatting when I chose 'DAY' granularity (it's used for reports, granularities are day, month, year), and the SQL should return the days and the values, the day formatting is sent back as ''2020-10-%d" which is really weird. The same generated SQL from the logs returns the correct values when executed directly on the database using MySQL Workbench for example.

Comment: Hmm. I abandoned doing it in MySQL and instead used JavaScript to deal with the formatting and everything was much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Waking up the thread...
To deal with %d in javascript strings, you must double it: '%%d-%b%y'.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.query("SELECT id,Names,DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth,'% %M %D %Y') FROM artists;"
```

This is the syntax you can use inside expressJS and Mysql